# Hosting a file and retrieving raw format through internet

Tags: java, android, file, server, host

I am crrently working on an Android application. I need a way of getting to a text file from an url like so: http://www.example.com/example.txt

However I cannot find a way to host this file in a way that I can access it through an URL which ends with".txt" (which I need to use in order to read the contents in it, in my case).

I have tried using 000webhost as a free alternaative, but the link it gives for the txt file straiht up does not show anything even htough it has content in it.

I am trying to access the information in a text file from internet with Java in Android, any alternate solutions would help a lot. Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: android couldn't care less what the url for your file is. a url is just an address. it doesn't have end with .txt in order to serve up a text file. basically you're asking for a hoster that can serve up a .txt file as a url, and that's offtopic - this site is for programming questions, not choosing a web host.

Comment: @MarcB Well, lets just say then, that my application needs a way of reading (parsing, really) content from the web (content being set up by me. As you said: a method of hosting files as URL's, either with 3rd party software or not). I am sure other people can answer this question properly instead of marking it off as off-topic. I am in need of a solution, should I set up something like FreeNas, should I use Microsoft server? How that would effect my preexisting code...? I am here for people to be able to help me and vice versa but honestly toxic people like you completely ruin the experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) or [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for hosting your site if it is a web app.
The learning curve for this would be steep if you are not aware of ssh and git but it's worth it if you are building web apps.

If you have a static website you could go forward with [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/) or a similar service.

If you just want to host a single txt file Use dropbox or Google Drive and obtain a direct link for it.

On the android end you would access the file like you would consume any other REST API. You could write the code for this by hand or You could use a library like Volley and perform a StringRequest which will read the response of your Request(In this case, the txt file) as a single String.